# Can IP header TTL values be exploited as an attack vector? If so, what can protect against that?

Tags: network, ip

As per some network certification training material, I noticed the following description of the `Time To Live` IP header:

> The time to live (TTL) is set into a packet when it's originally generated.  If it doesn't get to where it's supposed to go before the TTL expires, boom - it's gone.  This stops IP packets from continuously circling the network looking for a home.

That got me to thinking though.  Could this header be exploited and set to a really high value thus generating excessive network load/volume? If so, what controls could stop this type of behavior?  A policy enforced on a firewall or router?

Comment: TTL is not actually time, it's a hop-count limit. It is an 8-bit field, the maximum value is 255 so *really high values* are not possible. Various operating systems characteristically set a particular starting value of TTL. This is used as part of packet fingerprinting to attempt to identify the host computer OS sending the packet.

Answer (score 3):

> Could this header be exploited and set to a really high value thus
> generating excessive network load/volume?

No; each device in the path decrements the TTL, but decrementing a big number is no more expensive than decrementing a small number.  Knowing most packets rarely exceed their TTL, increasing the TTL won't cause the packet to traverse the network any longer than it would otherwise.

The one aggressive use the TTL can be put to is [firewalking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewalk_(computing)).  By sending packets with carefully crafted TTLs to a destination behind the firewall, you can map out what the firewall and devices behind it are permitting.

Answer (score 1):

In reality, high TTL values are used **for** security, not against it.

- From Cisco Security: [TTL Expiry Attack Identification and Mitigation](https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/resources/ttl_expiry_attack.html):

  > Most modern operating systems and network devices use a large default
  > TTL value when originating packets; default values of 128 or 255 are
  > commonplace. This fact, in conjunction with typical network diameters
  > and path lengths across the Internet, makes the presence of low TTL
  > values within legitimate packets unlikely.
  >
  > It is recommended that enterprises filter incoming packets with low
  > TTL values at untrusted-to-trusted network boundaries. While filtering
  > such packets will prevent remote users from tracerouting into the
  > network (outbound traceroute is unaffected), it will also eliminate a
  > significant denial of service attack vector. As an additional benefit,
  > filtering packets with low TTL values will eliminate certain firewall
  > rule mapping techniques such as those used by Firewalk as well as IDS
  > evasion techniques.
- The Generalized TTL Security Mechanism (GTSM), [RFC 5082](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5082), detects adjacent routers by setting the highest possible value (`255`) for TTL. If the packets are expected to be coming from the adjacent router, the receiver can simply drop all packets that have TTL lower than 254. This is not an efficient security measure against everything and not designed for authentication, but as the packets can easily be dropped based on a small header, it significantly decreases processing on the control plane.